# Как создать таблицу и записать данные в нее с помощью плагина SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova, angular

Есть проект, есть модуль app.module.ts, есть Класс, в котором был создан Конструктор Базы Данных.
Сейчас стоит задача создать таблицу, есть рабочий код:

```html
myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS codesundar (id integer primary key, title text, desc text)', [],
function(tx, result) {
alert("Table created successfully");
},
function(error) {
alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
});
});
```

Вопрос в том, в каком файле выполнять эту транзакцию и, после успешного выполнения данной транзакции, где новосозданную таблицу посмотреть?

Полагаю, что при старте проекта (инициализации) и создается табличка. Вопрос, какой код писать в конструктуре?

Код файла main.ts:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

</script>
```

Дерево проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код файла app.module.ts:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

'use strict';
class DataBase {
  constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) {  // Начало конструктора
      this.sqlite.create({
          name: 'data.db',
          location: 'default'
      })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        debugger;
          db.executeSql('create table Newslist(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
            .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
      });
  } // конец конструктора 
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Код файл app.component.ts:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { TabsPage } from './pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: После конструктора вы не сможете писать. Пишите в конструкторе. Обычно в проектах на ангуляр есть один входной компонент, обычно это `AppComponent`. Можете в нем написать.

Comment: Нужен созданный объект внутри конструктора. Только тогда консоль покажет что-то. Пока же ничего нет. Попробую AppComponent добавить.

Comment: Я не понял ваш комментарий. Что означает *Нужен созданный объект внутри конструктора.*? Лучше приведите в вопросе структуру вашего проекта. И содержимое главного модуля и файла 'main.ts'. Найдите, где вызывается функция `bootstrapModule`.

Comment: main.ts добавлен, дерево проекта тоже. Без созданного объекта конструктор  выведет пустую строку. Необходим объект.

Comment: Отлично, видно, что у вас главный модуль - `AppModule`. Следовательно ищите `AppModule`, в нем будет указан первый\главный компонент. Обычно это `AppComponent`. Ищите в  `AppModule` строчку `bootstrap:`. Затем в том компоненте, в конструкторе, пишите ваш код.

Comment: Вот в конструкторе компонента `IonicApp` и пишите ваш код. Кстати,  `pages` логичнее было бы внутри директории `app` держать.

Comment: Нашел bootstrap строку bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ]

Comment: Добавил Pages в App.  Прошу прощения, что значит, внутри IonicApp писать? Есть bootstrap: [IonicApp] . Внутри квадратных скобок или где?

Comment: У вас должен быть компонент `IonicApp`. Найдите файл, скорее всего будет называться `ionicapp.component` или как-то похоже. Вот в нем, в конструкторе, пишите.

Comment: Нашел app.component.ts . Стало быть, код с конструктором из файла app.module.ts мигрирует в app.component.ts?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79785/discussion-between-stepan-kasyanenko-and-dmitry-nikitin).